# How to save user preferences?

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons

We're developing a Gmail Addon to help internal staff to handle customers' email.

Our card widget will have a table with 2 column; first cell of every row will host, one or more domains, and the 2nd one will contains an *editable text box* with the default label that the addon will add to this user.

I'd like to allow user to *change* the default label, to adapt to his/her preferences and actual labelling method, adopted in some cases since years.

So the problem: **how to save the user preferences**, the user settings, of our addon only of course, but keeping **related to user account**? The goal is **allow user to login with different devices and find the same settings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sample Gmail add-ons projects](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/gmail-add-ons-samples) that Google have published on Github should help you. In particular I've just found [this Settings.js source file](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/gmail-add-ons-samples/blob/master/meeting-assistant/src/Settings.js).

The core seems to be

```
var savedSettings = cachedPropertiesForUser_().get("settings", {});
```

But I've not used this in anger.